# Traduction pour « Factorization Algebra »

Tags: terminologie, mathématiques

J’étudie en ce moment une structure algébrique apparue en théorie des représentations et en théorie des champs conformes du nom de « Factorization Algebra ».

Quelle serait une bonne traduction en Français ?

- *Algèbre factorisante* a été proposé, mais c’est laid ;
- *Algèbre de factorisation* est le terme employé aujourd’hui, à défaut d’autre chose ;
- *Algèbre à factorisation* a aussi été proposé.

Qu’en pensez-vous ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question... il me semble qu' *algèbre de factorisation* est le nom de l'objet en français, et donc qu'il est trop tard pour lui donner un autre nom.

Answer (score 3):

#### Commençons par regarder les définitions des deux prépositions en jeu

La préposition *à* « introduit un complément marquant un rapport de direction, de destination, de lieu d'appartenance, de moyen, de manière ou de temps. »<sup>[source](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/a-1/)</sup> On retrouve environ la même définition dans le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/%C3%A0/5), la principale différence est que celui-ci ajoute « l'utilisation de *à* pour marquer la **caractérisation** » *(c'est ce qui rend le choix entre les expressions plus difficile)*.

La préposition *de* « [marque] l'origine, le lieu, la cause, la manière ou le mode d'action, la **qualité**, ou introduisant un complément d'objet indirect. »<sup>[source](http://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition.php?mot=de)</sup> C'est aussi ce qu'écrit le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/de/21598).

<sub>Toute accentuation est mienne</sub>

---

#### Revenons à nos moutons

Dans notre cas, je dirais que la factorisation représente, selon moi, une *qualité*<sup>[1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qualit%C3%A9)</sup> de l'algèbre. On vient ici qualifier un sous ensemble de l'algèbre s'attachant à la factorisation. Sachant cela, on est directement dans la définition du *de*. Par conter, le mot *caractéristique* est très près de *qualité* et donc puisque *à* peut marquer la *caractérisation* l'expression serait aussi acceptable.

Personnellement, j'opterais pour *algèbre de factorisation*. Toutefois, tel que soulevé par Stéphane, surtout en algèbre, l'expression *de* est souvent utilisée pour caractériser les éléments utilisés par la dite algèbre, par exemple [algèbre d'ensembles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alg%C3%A8bre_d%27ensembles) ou [algèbre de processus](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alg%C3%A8bre_de_processus). Alors, pour être sûr d'enlever l’ambiguïté j'opterais pour

> algèbre **de la** factorisation

Le *de la* vient préciser que c'est l'algèbre qui traite du sujet de la factorisation.

<sup>[1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qualit%C3%A9)</sup><sub>Caractéristique de nature, bonne ou mauvaise, d'une chose ou d'une personne.</sub>

Comment: Contrairement aux exemples que tu donnes, les éléments d'une « algèbre de factorisation » ne sont pas des « factorisations ». L'explication donnée ne me parait pas vraiment convaincante. (Et j'aurais tendance à pencher pour « algèbre à factorisation »).

Comment: @Stéphane Très bon point, par contre je reste sur ma tendance à prioriser une utilisation de *de*! J'ai modifié ma réponse pour essayer de mieux refléter les raisons qui me font pencher vers le *de*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *algèbre à factorisation* me fait un peu trop penser à *anneau à division*, si je comprends bien le sujet il ne s'agit pas d'algèbres particulière dans lesquelles on peut factoriser (puisqu'on peut toujours), donc *algèbre à factorisation* est trompeur.

Comment: @Evpok: Je crois qu'on va rapidement manquer de prépositions si on exclue tout ce qui ressemble à quelque chose de légèrement différent :-) (*avec* ne me parait pas judicieux non plus…)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez True, mais *algèbre de la factorisation* me choque moins. Après sans savoir précisément de quoi il retourne…

Comment: @Evpok: Perso, ça me parait trop général. Mais ça ressemble quand même à du français :-)

Comment: @Evpok : Heureusement, en Français on utilise « corps gauche ».

Comment: @DamienL Ah ? Je ne suis pas expert mais j'ai toujours entendu parler d'*anneau à division* ou de *corps non-commutatif*.

Comment: Corps gauche devient en anglais « skew-field ».